# how to count row from single column by specific digit stored in mysql in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I want to count total number of rows in a specific column by specific digit from mysql database.

Suppose I have "RatingTable" and My database structure is:

```
id
username
rating
```

Now suppose I have some stored values like:

```
id : 1
username: A1
rating: 3


id : 2
username: A2
rating: 2


id : 3
username: A3
rating: 5


id : 4
username: A4
rating: 5


id : 5
username: A5
rating: 3


id : 6
username: A6
rating: 5
```

Now I want to select all rows from "rating" column where rating = 5, so it should return id:3, id:4, id:6 rows.

I am trying:

```
$starRatingQuery = "SELECT * FROM RatingTable WHERE rating = 5";
$starRatingResults = $db->query($starRatingQuery);
$RatingRowCount = mysqli_num_rows($starRatingResults);
var_dump("Star Rating 5 Rows are : ".$RatingRowCount);
```

Output

```
string(26) "Star Rating 1 Rows are : 1"
```

It always return 1 row.

Same thing it return for rating = 5, rating = 2

I am not able to select a specific digit in a rating column.

Any idea or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: you should not mix up different stiles use $RatingRowCount = $starRatingResults ->num_rows;

Comment: Are you sure your query isn't actually `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RatingTable WHERE rating = 5` because that *will* always return 1 row

Comment: While I'm not familiar with PHP, I doubt the records are really inserted into the table. How did you insert the data? Did you do it in a transaction? If so, have you commited said transaction? This happens very often to me. If you simply remove the WHERE clause, does it return more than 1 record? If you use phpMyAdmin or whatver database admin tool, what does it show?

Also please review your post tags - you added mysql and sql-server. Pretty sure it's only mysql.

Comment: I’m wondering if she’s ever actually executing the function?? Does $db->query(STATEMENT)->execute(); return what you’re looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this query: SELECT COUNT(*) as counter FROM RatingTable WHERE rating = 5